# POSIX: Why is signal blocking required for sigwait?

Tags: signals, posix

I want to implement the following functionality (not multi threaded):

When signal X is received and the process is synchronously waiting with `sigwait` on X, the process resumes, does some work, and comes back to the `sigwait` on X. If the signal is received while the process is not waiting, a custom handler is executed.
Using `SIGALRM` this represents a periodic task. And if the handler is executed, it means the deadline was missed.

In my understanding of POSIX signals

- sigwait requires that the signals are blocked
- the handler will not execute if the signal is blocked

The [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html) states regarding sigwait:

> `int sigwait(const sigset_t *restrict set, int *restrict sig);`
>
> The signals defined by `set` shall have been blocked at the time of the call to `sigwait();` otherwise, the behavior is undefined. The effect of `sigwait()` on the signal actions for the signals in `set` is unspecified.

I tried it on Linux without the signal being blocked, similar to this:

```
void handler(int sig)
{
    printf("Deadline missed!\n");
}
```

```
sigemptyset(s)
sigaddset(s, SIGALRM)
sigaction(SIGALRM, action_with_handler, NULL)

while(1) {
    int sig;
    sigwait(s, sig);
    // do some work here
}
```

And this seems to work. However this might be implementation dependent for Linux/glibc. So I guess on some systems it might execute the handler instead of the `sigwait` or even both.

*1) Am I correct in assuming the portable way would be the following?*

```
while(1) {
    int sig;
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, s, NULL)
    sigwait(s, &sig);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, s, NULL)
    // do some heavy lifting
}
```

It seems overly verbose.

*2) Why does `sigwait` require the signal(s) to be blocked? Is there a reason why it doesn't block the signals on its own (and unblocks them afterwards, if they were not blocked before)?*

Edit: It seems Linux is actually doing that on a call to `sigwait`/`sigtimedwait`: It unblocks signals based on the given mask when starting to wait and doesn't really care about what was blocked before ([src](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/92ed301919932f777713b9172e525674157e983d/kernel/signal.c#L3465-L3478)). It actually looks like it unblocks the signals in `tsk->blocked` and does not revert that change. Which is surprising, but maybe I misunderstand the code.

Edit2: Actually it is reverted. I guess this is what `real_blocked` is for (the temp value). I cannot find a good documentation for the difference between `real_blocked` and `blocked`.